# Google Drive: sign in failed. Error signing into the specified account

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-play-services

I'm trying to allow my users to select files to be uploaded to my server for more processing. I'm not able to get the sign in working and i'm not able to figure out why. Below is the code I use to initiate the handshake with Google:

```
public GoogleApiClient getGoogleApiClient() {
    if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
                .addApi(Drive.API)
                .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
    }
    return mGoogleApiClient;
}

private void getDataFromGoogleDrive() {
    try {
        IntentSender intentSender = Drive.DriveApi.newOpenFileActivityBuilder().build(getGoogleApiClient());
        getActivity().startIntentSenderForResult(intentSender, RC_SIGN_IN, null, 0, 0, 0);
    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Unable to send intent", e);
        getGoogleApiClient().connect();
    }
}

public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    if (getGoogleApiClient().isConnected()) {
        getDataFromGoogleDrive();
    }
}

public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
}

public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
        try {
            connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(getActivity(), RC_SIGN_IN);
        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
            // Unable to resolve, message user appropriately
        }
    } else {
        GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(connectionResult.getErrorCode(), getActivity(), 0).show();
    }
}


protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        if (!getGoogleApiClient().isConnecting()) {
            getGoogleApiClient().connect();
        }
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

I also followed directions here:

https://developers.google.com/drive/android/auth#connecting_and_authorizing_the_google_drive_android_api

Is there something i'm missing here? My credentials are accurate since i'm also using the same for Google Maps. In my manifest I have the below:

```
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="@string/google_api_key" />
```

I'm noticing that Google Drive doesn't require me to pass in the api key? Is that correct? Other than that I can't think of anything--but the documentation doesn't say that it is required.

My `build.grade` file dependencies are here:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same thing.  Looks like you need to also setup an OAuth 2.0 credential as well.  Once I did that, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not added the `com.android.application` in your *build.gradle* file. The document you are referring to **authorize the requests** but not to authenticate.

To know more about the authentication for to access Google Drive, please refer to the official documentation on [Android Quick-start to access Drive REST API](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/android).

This includes:

- Acquire a SHA1 fingerprint.
- Enable the Drive API
- Create a new Android Project
- Configure the Project
- Add project Source Files
- Run the app

Hope this Helps!!

Comment: Yeah, saw that link also. Not sure, did verbatim whats on that page.